# frisby.js post body content syntax

Tags: javascript, html, json, frisby.js

I have a UI and server data exchange that works well but I wanted to start testing new development with Frisby.js. The UI has a JavaScript form manager that uses jQuery.  My request body is a JavaScript object that is first serialized with JSON.stringify.

```
var msg = {form:"login",data{username:"elmer",password:"wabbit"}};
var json_msg = JSON.stringify(msg);
```

Then it is sent by jQuery:

```
$.ajax(
    url: baseUrl+"forms/"+call,
    data: { req: json_msg },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(msg){...
```

The raw body content received at the server looks like this:

```
req=%7B%22form%22%3A%22login%22%2C%22data%22%3A%7B%22username%22%3A%22elmer%22%2C%22password%22%3A%wabbit%22%7D%7D
```

Since this raw body content is what my server expects and uses successfully, I have tried several combinations of content-type headers and content formats but Frisby.js chokes on them or sends the wrong body.

NOTE: 
1. First the message (a JavaScript object) must be serialized.
2. Then req=[serialized_message] must be URIencoded.
These two steps are performed easily with jQuery.ajax() but seemingly are
impossible on Frisby.js

I tried:
  using unserialized JavaScript object,
  using serialized JavaScript object and
  serialized and URIencoded text (shown here)

```
msg = "%7B%22form%22%3A%22login%22%2C%22data%22%3A%7B%22username%22%3A%22elmer%22%2C%22password%22%3A%wabbit%22%7D%7D";

frisby.create('Login on HHHLEG web site.')
  .addHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')
  .post('http://hhhleg/forms/login', req=msg )
```

The above code ends up with nothing in the body when it gets to the server.  I suspect there is some simple syntax issue or a content-type issue or Frisby.js cannot perform the combination of serialization and URI encoding because it chokes on the characters involved.

Answer (score 0):

Frisby probably expects a JSON encoded request body, rather than jQuery's default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Try setting the `contentType`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl+"forms/"+call,
    data: { req: json_msg },
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    // other properties...
});
```

Comment: That was my first attempt. What I got was a serialized JavaScript object.  When my server looked for 'req' in the post body it wasn't there as it normally would be when sent from my UI app.  Check out the raw body normally received from the app.  The problem is how to get that content when using Frisby.js.

Comment: Ok. Can you update the question to say that and I'll delete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In similar issue for me helps following:
 1. Create variable with needed name (in your case is "req") and send it with msg content
 2. Use not ordinary frisby js post constructor, but following:

```
...
    frisby.create('Send valid data in post')
        .post(YourPath,
            req, //before it we need to assign to it value by
                 //"var req = msg" or any byte array
            {
                json: false,
                headers: {
                    "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
                    "Authorization": your.authToken //if needed
                }
            })
        .expectStatus(200)
...
```

In my case I've tried to send image byte array, but met similar issue with URLencoded message and JSON-form sending request.
If it's doesn't help or seems like not your case - you can visit https://github.com/vlucas/frisby/tree/legacy-0.x/examples page for more examples of POST request with data sending.